# (Webpack) How to reference manifest.json in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, webpack, manifest.json

Using Webpack with Vuejs and Asp.Net. I basically want to create a separate cshtml file which is essentially a html template, and include links based on the manifest.json output since the hash changes everytime i build the Vue App. Manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
  "main.js": "css.d915ef.js",
  "main.css": "main.d915ef.css"
}
```

But how do I do this in my index.cshtml:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/main.css">
```

This current code doesnt work but is the rough idea of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: what's your webpack setup?

Comment: I’m using standard webpack config (to vue?) other than routing my output to a /static folder, and using html-webpack-plugin to output the manifest file

Comment: you need to use MiniCssExtractPlugin and ManifestPlugin. They will include bundled css into your index.html

Comment: alright thank you!